# Problems deploying farm-solution

Tags: deployment, solution-deployment, farm-solution

After doing the solution retract and removed, I ran the command --> Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath 'pathSolution.wsp'

However, when I access the 'Manage farm solutions' page, there is no solution for me to deploy it.

What could be happening?

Comment: is add command completed successfully? are you seeing any issue in the Event log? try to reset IIS on central admin server?

Answer (score 0):

The deploy WSP solution operation consists of two cmdlets

**(1) Uploads a SharePoint solution package to the farm.**

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath 'C:\pathSolution.wsp'
```

> **Note**: Make sure you have specified the correct solution path like `C:\pathSolution.wsp`

**(2) Deploys an installed SharePoint solution on the farm**

```
Install-SPSolution -Identity pathSolution.wsp -GACDeployment
```

For more details check [Install and deploy a SharePoint (wsp) solution package using SharePoint PowerShell](https://blog.devoworx.net/2012/12/20/how-to-deploy-a-sharepoint-wsp-solution-package/)